# MySQL - Listar resultados de 2 tabelas

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas com o mesmo campo e preciso fazer um `SELECT` com duas condições, estou tentando esse código mas está listando 2 vez o resultado só da primeira tabela (`entrada`), nada da segunda tabela (`saida`):

```
SELECT * FROM entrada, saida WHERE entrada.idUsuario = '1' OR saida.idUsuario = '1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui usando `UNION`:

```
(SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE idUsuario LIKE '1')
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM saida WHERE idUsuario LIKE '1')
```